# Получение event.keyCode в функции, вызываемой в цикле

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы функция `OnKeyDown`, вызываемая в цикле несколько раз в секунду, возвращала `e.keyCode`?

```
OnKeyDown: function() {
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == 68) {
            return e.keyCode;
        }
    }
    return ?;
},
```

Comment: При таком коде - никак. Вы в функции `OnKeyDown` добавляете обработчик события. Само событие произойдёт позже, и функция `OnKeyDown` к этому времени уже закончит своё выполнение. А зачем вам это - какую цель вы преследуете?

Comment: отследить нажатие кнопки(например 'd') так что бы можно было вызывать функцию и проврять keyCode

Comment: Вот, допустим, вызываете вы эту функцию: `myObj.OnKeyDown()`. Что вы ожидаете при этом? Что она будет "висеть" до тех пор, пока вы не нажмёте какую-то клавишу? Или что она сразу вернёт результат, состоящий из `keyCode` когда-то нажатой (и сохраненной в памяти) клавиши? Если же вы хотите просто добавить обработчик события, то такой `return` в нём бессмысленен - логика работы с `keyCode` должна быть либо прямо внутри обработчика, либо передаваться в заданную callback-функцию.

Comment: По моей логике эта функция запускаеться в функции Update(), которая в свою очередь запускаеться с частотою 1000/60 сек. и если нажатия не будет то myObj.OnKeyDown() вернет что-то типа undefined если будет нажатие то вернет кейкод. Поправте меня если я не прав.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно логика, связанная с обработкой событий, располагается непосредственно внутри обработчика события.
Однако если по какой-то причине нужно выполнять обработку в "основном цикле" программы, то можно поступить так:

- в обработчике события сохранять полученное значение (например, в глобальной переменной)
- в основном цикле проверять наличие сохраненного значения. Если оно есть (например, если переменная не равна `null`), то копировать его себе, а сохраненное значение удалять, дабы на следующей итерации цикла не считать его повторно.

Пример такой реализации:

```js
//Обработчик события, сохраняющий результат в глобальную переменную
var savedKeyCode = null;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  savedKeyCode = event.keyCode;
});

//В OnKeyDown происходит работа только с сохранённым значением
var myObj = {
  OnKeyDown: function() {
    var keyCode = savedKeyCode;
    savedKeyCode = null;
    return keyCode;
  }
};

//Основной цикл, выполняющийся примерно 10 раз в секунду
setInterval(function() {
  var keyCode = myObj.OnKeyDown();
  if (keyCode != null) {
    console.log("Got: ", keyCode);
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Я кажись понял, щас попытаюсь подогнать.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy на здоровье. Если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как подходящий (галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 0):

За 2 минуты набросал [Небольшой пример](https://embed.plnkr.co/i3P5GshXR0WMsl2moxLS/)

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;            
    var event = e.keyCode;
    return event; // но зачем возвращать значение в такой функции?
}
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events

Comment: 1. в чем, собственно, проблема (при выводе)?
2. нет, использовал en.stackoverflow

Comment: ни разу на мой код не похоже, ножно соблюдать структуру

Comment: как сделать чтобы функция OnKeyDown возвращала e.keyCode?

Comment: 1. Код должен быть прямо в ответе. 2. Код должен решать описанную в вопросе проблему, а не быть абстрактным примером. 3. Сколько времени вы потратили на написание кода не несёт полезной информации для ответа.

Comment: Как можно это запустить  как функцию?

Comment: Напишите конкретно свою задачу. 
Обычно в html есть какой-то input#demo, в js его выбирают и вешают ему событие OnKeyDown: document.getElementById("demo").onkeydown = function(e) { ...}

Comment: мне нужна функция которую я могу присвоить переменной var key = myObj.OnKeyDown() P.s ета функция вызывается в другом файле